# Position sticky on thead

Tags: html, css

As you might know, `position: sticky;` has landed in Webkit ([demo](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html)).
So far I can see this only works within the parent element. But I'd like to know if I can use this in a scrolling div with a table.

So it needs to 'listen' on the scrolling event of the `div`, not the `table`.

I know I can do this with javascript and absolute positioning, but I was wondering if the `sticky-positioning` would support this.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Position sticky on *thead th* works in 2018!**

In your stylesheets just add this one line:

```
thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

Your table will need to include *thead* and *th* for this to style.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
            <th>column 4</th>            
        </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      // your body code
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, if you have multiple rows in *thead*, you can select the first one to remain sticky:

```
thead tr:first-child th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

As of March 2018 support is pretty much there across modern browsers
ref: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

*Credit goes to @ctf0 for this one ([ref comment made 3 Dec 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead/49270067#comment82195060_43895506))*

Comment: It doesn’t work as expected (`thead { position: sticky }`) because of this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=702927

Comment: works for me with just `thead` as the selector and `overflow: auto` on a parent element of the table.

Comment: can it work if i have multiple row th in the thead ?

Comment: Great answer. The trick is that the position must go on the th element, and the parent cannot have overflow: hidden.

Comment: Important to add here: firefox is able to sticky the entire THEAD, even if it has multiple TRs. Chrome cannot. You have to sticky all cells individually, and give the first row of cells `top:0` and subsequent rows `top:20px`, `top:40px`, etc... Awful DX

Comment: Default overflow will be required on a parent element, which you can reset with `overflow:visible`. Sticky is *broken* both for `hidden` and `auto` on a parent element.

Comment: @Nux I havent tested what you are saying, but are you suggesting everyone also needs to add this as well as the above? ---->  tr { overflow:visible}

Comment: @Evolve `overflow:visible` is the default. So normally you don't need that. But if you did modify overflow, then you need to revert it to `visible` value.

Answer (score 14):

If you need sticky header for chrome only then you can set `position: sticky; top: some_value` (`top` property is mandatory) for `td` element in a `thead` element.

See:

```
<table border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style='position: sticky; top: -1px;background: red'>Sticky Column</td>
      <td>Simple column</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

[table with a stiky header](https://codepen.io/bioform/pen/XRZBEW)

Comment: for me the solution was `thead th {position: sticky; top: 0;}`

Comment: This is the better answer imo. Just using `position: sticky` did not work for me. Adding the `top` rule worked perfectly!

Comment: great....been looking for long....this is helpful for chrome browser.....also you need to set background-color and color properly to match up.....may helpful for someone.

Comment: @FilipeEsperandio That's a bug in Chrome/FF that's oddly been marked as resolved in Chrome's tracker. It's frustratingly one of the few things Edge gets right.

Answer (score 10):

`position: sticky` **doesn't work** with table elements (as long as their `display` attribute starts with `table-`) since tables are not part of [specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/):

> Other kinds of layout, such as tables, "floating" boxes, ruby annotations, grid layouts, columns and basic handling of normal "flow" content, are described in other modules.

---

**Edit**: As Jul 2019 according to https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky Firefox supports this feature and Chrome has at least support for `<th>` tag.

Comment: Not sure about that. Mozilla is apparently working on shipping this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975644

Comment: @retrovertigo And it's fixed now.

Comment: @Qwertie Thanks for the update :) "VERIFIED FIXED in Firefox 59"

Comment: Position Sticky for thead works in 2018, see updated answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49270067/172651

Comment: Correction to the July 2019 edit: Firefox supports `position: sticky` on `thead` elements **on MacOS**. From my testing, Firefox 69 on Windows royally screws it up, ignoring background colour, but not text colour (yielding a completely illegible header) and making the element randomly appear and disappear when scrolling. Webkit doesn’t currently support it for `thead`, treating it as `position: static` (or relative – not sure if the difference is really meaningful for a `thead` element).

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out it `position: sticky` only works in the window and not in a scrolling div.

I created a [test-case](http://jsfiddle.net/willemdewit/xNsaM/) with a very long table with a table header:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

div.testTable {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table.stickyHead thead {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: grey;
}

table.stickyHead td,
table.stickyHead th {
  padding: 2px 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Position sticky</h1>
<div class="testTable">
  <table class="stickyHead">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>column 1</th>
        <th>column 2</th>
        <th>column 3</th>
        <th>column 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, if you remove the overflow from the wrapper and make your window not so tall, the table-head is sticking to the top of the window. I doesn't apply to the wrapping `div` even if you make give the `div` `position: relative`

Comment: The test case doesn't work in Firefox nor in Chrome (support for `position:sticky` was probably removed from Blink). Current support http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: there is a bug for it in bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975644

Comment: This is not correct (or is no longer correct).  I ran through your test and got the sticky header working fine with just two changes: I dropped the `-webkit-` prefix off of the position, and set the position on the th, not the thead: http://jsfiddle.net/xNsaM/128/  Works fine.

Comment: looks like it just works on firefox now, it however does not work if overflow-x is set to auto

Answer (score 3):

Setting the position:sticky for the *thead* is enough, no need to set it for *th* :

```
table.StickyHeader thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Tested in:

Edge 105.0.1343.42 ,
Firefox 105.0 ,
Chrome 105.0.5195.127 ,
Opera 91.0.4516.16

But, Firefox can not render borders of *th* when position of *thead* is set to sticky and *th* has background-color:

```
table.StickyHeader th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hva6X.png)

[Edge, Chrome, Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5QaP.png)

Comment: The easiest solution so far. Also, the only one that worked for me considering a difficult style setup for table

Answer (score 0):

Caution:

`position:sticky` doesn't work anymore on Google Chrome in 2019, try to use `fixed` instead or `display:inline-block`

Comment: Taken from a previous answer, please be carreful using sticky:
This does not work on Chrome v35 through v51, Chrome 52 reenables this with the experimental web platform features flag. Starting from Chrome 56 position: sticky works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If it ain't working, adding a z-index to thead or th might help.