# Position Sticky on <td> with colspan?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It seems like `sticky` doesn't work on `<td>` with `colspan`. Is there a way around it?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #146775;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky-header:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.sticky-row {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 23px; /* This seems to work differently for Safari, FF, Chrome etc. Here adjusted for FF */
  background: #1C4464;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}
.sticky-row:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100px; /* How can I make this dynamic? */
  z-index: 2;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 113px;
}

.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #569CA8;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px; /* How can I make this dynamic? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 1</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 2</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 3</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 4</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 5</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 7</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 8</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 9</td>
        <td class="sticky-header">Header 10</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 1</td>
        <td class="sticky-row" colspan="9">How can I make this sticky?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 2<span>Dirty way of making sticky</span></td>
        <td class="sticky-row" colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 3</td>
        <td class="sticky-row" colspan="9">How can I make this sticky?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it goes against the purpose of tabular display, can't this part be outside of the `table`?

Comment: @Kaddath My table is much more complex and contains both sticky columns to the left, a sticky header and sticky rows when scrolling down. The row with the colspan functions as a row-divider so there are multiple of those. I've had things outside of the table before and it's a mess to sync up with scrolls and changes of column widths unfortunately.

Comment: Hum i see, can your example snippet be a little more representative of what you have then?

Comment: For reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead

Comment: @Kaddath Updated the snippet!

Comment: I figured out a dirty way of achieving what I want. Check out the second blue row in the snippet! :) Suggestions of a better solution are welcome.

Comment: @SeaBass the thing is now when you scroll down, the row 2 "Dirty way" superimposes with the row 3 "How can I"..

Comment: Yes, I had to add a background to that text. Getting filthier and filthier hehe.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's already sticky, the problem is due to the width of the td there is no reason for it to move.  So to make them both sticky change the **colspan** on the second td (to make it even better give it also a left of 50px to make them move next to each other). Hope this awnsered your question.

**UPDATE**:

the colspan on the 2nd td is why your code doesn't work, i fixed this by replacing the structure to this

```
<tr class="darkblue">
    <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 1</td>
    <td class="sticky-row" colspan>How can I make this sticky?</td>
    <td colspan="8"></td>
  </tr>
```

and added an extra css class to fix the background color of the tr

```
.darkblue {
  background: #1C4464;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-row {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 23px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Full code for reference down below

```css
    body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sticky-header {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #146775;
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky-header:first-child {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
}

.darkblue {
  background: #1C4464;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky-row {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 23px;
  /* background: #1C4464; */
  color: white;
  z-index: 3;
}
.sticky-row:nth-child(2) {
  left: 100px; /* How can I make this dynamic? */
  z-index: 2;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 113px;
}

.sticky-column {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #569CA8;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px; /* How can I make this dynamic? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table cellspacing="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 1</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 2</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 3</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 4</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 5</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 7</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 8</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 9</td>
    <td class="sticky-header">Header 10</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="darkblue">
    <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 1</td>
    <td class="sticky-row" colspan>How can I make this sticky?</td>
    <td colspan="8"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="darkblue">
    <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 2<span>Dirty way of making sticky</span></td>
    <td class="sticky-row" colspan="9"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-row">Sticky Row 3</td>
    <td class="sticky-row" colspan="9">How can I make this sticky?</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sticky-column">Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
    <td>Column 7</td>
    <td>Column 8</td>
    <td>Column 9</td>
    <td>Column 10</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Will try, but colspan 1? Isn't that a little ugly? Also is there a way to make it dynamic so I don't have to set 50px exactly?

Comment: It might but you can change it to whatever you want, i just used 1 to illustrate my solution.

Comment: hm, it actually wont work for me with an inexact colspan. Look how your text got divided into 5 lines. I need that on one line and setting white-space: nowrap makes the column above/below change in width too :/

Comment: I updated my original post with one way that gives me what I want.

Comment: Thank you! The blue row background disappears and only the text stays. Also the Column 2 gets the same width as the sticky row second column.

Comment: You have to add the *darkblue* class to the blue rows to show the background again. This probably will fix the width aswell

Comment: Do you think I can use the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags for this or are they basically functioning like `<tr>` and `<th|td>`?

Comment: @Seregmir thank you dear friend! just saved my day ❤️

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the Solution for your original Question*. **Trying to help would be useless if you have a varying Question and keep changing the Question**

`position: sticky` doesn't work with table elements. Since, `top` and `bottom` doesn't work in table elements what we can do is line height of the non sticky `td` so that `sticky` `td` wouldn't overlap over `non-sticky` `td`

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="sticky left">Sticky</td>
            <td class="sticky" colspan="9">How can I make this sticky?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tableBody">
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
            <td>Column 7</td>
            <td>Column 8</td>
            <td>Column 9</td>
            <td>Column 10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Add `class` `left` for the sticky td that remains on the left side. Similarly manage the value of `left` in other `td`
. Also, add some `class` for non sticky `td` as `tableBody` in this example:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  background: white;
}
.left{
  left:0;
}
tr.tableBody
{
   line-height:50px;
}
```

Finally add your desired `CSS`.

[Please check this DEMO Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/6fqg2y1v/16/)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy didn't notice that OP has changed his Question

Comment: My original question is the same. I fleshed it out because it was requested. Thanks for the help. And sticky does work on table elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another not-too-ugly hack:

```
<tr>
   <th>
      <div class="outer_container">
         <div class="inner_container">
            Sticky Heading
         </div>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
   </th>
</tr>

th {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}

.outer_container {
    position: relative;
}

.inner_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The non-breaking space `&nbsp;` gives the `<th>` its normal behavior in terms of padding, margin, line-height etc.

Also, you need to set the `width` of your `inner_container` which is also kinda ugly and not so dynamic but it works.