# Dynamic Table with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, php, css, scrollbar

i have a problem with my dynamically genareted table. Im trying to fix this for a long time.. :D I finally decided to ask some people.

Just sayn that this is my first WebApp and i normally dont use html/css/js.

The table is wraped in a div, which defines the size of it. 
Also the table is reponsive (theres a bootstrap css behind) that means that theres no fixed col-width.

The problem is that if the table is too big and if i scroll down, you wont see the header anymore. 
Result: The user gets confused and dosnt know which data is in which row.

My Table:

```
div id="tblDiv" class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1">
        <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d4;"class="table table-striped table-sm" id="tblContent">


        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

My custom CSS:

```
.div1
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            overflow-x: auto; 
            overflow-y:auto;     
        } 

.wrapper1
        {
           /* overflow-x: hidden; 
            overflow-y:hidden;*/
            width:100%;
            height:81%;
        }
```

The Php Script which generates my table:

```
$anfrage = "SELECT TOP (".$MaxRecords.") * FROM Words WHERE (";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($rowsCsv); $i++)
    {

        if($i == 0)
        {

            $anfrage = $anfrage . $rowsCsv[$i] . " like N".$_POST['searchStg']. " ";
        }
        else
        {
            $anfrage = $anfrage . "or " . $rowsCsv[$i] . " like N".$_POST['searchStg']. " ";
        }
    }

    $anfrage = $anfrage . ")AND FirmenID = '".$_POST['CP']."'";

    $rs = odbc_exec($db, $anfrage);

    echo "<thead id='tblHeader' style='font-size:14pt' id='tblHeader'><tr>";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($rowsCsv); $i++)
    {
        if($i == 0)
        {
            echo "<td style='border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center'colspan='3'>Actions</td>";
        }

        echo "<td style='cursor:pointer' onclick='sortTable(".($i+3).");switchTH(".($i+1).")'><nobr>" . $rowsCsv[$i] . "</nobr></td>";
    }

    echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";

    while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
    {
        echo "<tr>";

        $guid =  '"' . odbc_result($rs,"Guid0") . '"';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($rowsCsv); $i++)
        {
            $col = odbc_result($rs,trim($rowsCsv[$i]));
            if($i == 0)
            {
                echo "<td style='text-align: center'><button onclick='EditID(".$guid.")' class='toolBtn'><img src='bilder/edit.png'></img></button><br><button style='color:red' onclick='deleteRow(".$guid.")' class='toolBtn'>-</button></td><td style='ext-align: center'><button onclick='copyID(".$guid.")' class='toolBtn'><img src='bilder/copy.png'></img></button></td><td style='border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center'><button onclick='setChecked(".$guid.",)' class='toolBtn'><img src='bilder/check.png'></img></button></td>";
            }


            if(trim($rowsCsv[$i]) == "lastCheck")
            {                    
                $timestamp = strtotime("-1 months");
                $stichtag = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

                if($col == "1999-12-24")
                {
                    echo "<td style='background-color:rgb(255,255,0,0.2)'>unchecked</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    if($col >= $stichtag)
                    echo "<td style='background-color:rgb(0,255,0,0.2)'>" . $col . "</td>";
                    if($col <  $stichtag)
                    echo "<td style='background-color:rgb(255,0,0,0.2)'>old / " . $col . "</td>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td>" . $col . "</td>";
            }
        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</tbody>";
```

A example result:

```
<div id="tblDiv" class="wrapper1">
<div class="div1">
    <table style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cdd0d4;" class="table table-striped table-sm" id="tblContent">
        <thead id="tblHeader" style="font-size:14pt">
            <tr>
                <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center" colspan="3">Actions</td>
                <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(3);switchTH(1)">
                    <nobr>lastCheck</nobr>
                </td>
                <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(4);switchTH(2)">
                    <nobr>JA_Word</nobr>
                </td>
                <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(5);switchTH(3)">
                    <nobr> EN_Word</nobr>
                </td>
                <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(6);switchTH(4)">
                    <nobr> DE_Word</nobr>
                </td>
                <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="sortTable(7);switchTH(5)">
                    <nobr> FR_Word</nobr>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <button onclick="EditID(&quot;61CA196B-8A4A-1AD5-7A2B-4F24DCAE1F0D&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                        <img src="bilder/edit.png">
                        </button>
                        <br>
                            <button style="color:red" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;61CA196B-8A4A-1AD5-7A2B-4F24DCAE1F0D&quot;)" class="toolBtn">-</button>
                        </td>
                        <td style="ext-align: center">
                            <button onclick="copyID(&quot;61CA196B-8A4A-1AD5-7A2B-4F24DCAE1F0D&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                <img src="bilder/copy.png">
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center">
                                <button onclick="setChecked(&quot;61CA196B-8A4A-1AD5-7A2B-4F24DCAE1F0D&quot;,)" class="toolBtn">
                                    <img src="bilder/check.png">
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0,0.2)">unchecked</td>
                                <td>2：円筒</td>
                                <td>2: CYLINDER</td>
                                <td>2: ZYLINDER</td>
                                <td>2: VERIN</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                    <button onclick="EditID(&quot;58108919-DDD0-2660-E832-F857C3DC5BA4&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                        <img src="bilder/edit.png">
                                        </button>
                                        <br>
                                            <button style="color:red" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;58108919-DDD0-2660-E832-F857C3DC5BA4&quot;)" class="toolBtn">-</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="ext-align: center">
                                            <button onclick="copyID(&quot;58108919-DDD0-2660-E832-F857C3DC5BA4&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                <img src="bilder/copy.png">
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center">
                                                <button onclick="setChecked(&quot;58108919-DDD0-2660-E832-F857C3DC5BA4&quot;,)" class="toolBtn">
                                                    <img src="bilder/check.png">
                                                    </button>
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0,0.2)">2019-02-20</td>
                                                <td>2：円筒</td>
                                                <td>2: CYLINDER</td>
                                                <td>2: ZYLINDER</td>
                                                <td>2: VERIN</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                                    <button onclick="EditID(&quot;244F012B-9293-4036-D6C2-C76130AE9552&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                        <img src="bilder/edit.png">
                                                        </button>
                                                        <br>
                                                            <button style="color:red" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;244F012B-9293-4036-D6C2-C76130AE9552&quot;)" class="toolBtn">-</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td style="ext-align: center">
                                                            <button onclick="copyID(&quot;244F012B-9293-4036-D6C2-C76130AE9552&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                <img src="bilder/copy.png">
                                                                </button>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center">
                                                                <button onclick="setChecked(&quot;244F012B-9293-4036-D6C2-C76130AE9552&quot;,)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                    <img src="bilder/check.png">
                                                                    </button>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0,0.2)">unchecked</td>
                                                                <td>自動ドアエアシリンダ（1M）</td>
                                                                <td>AIR CYLINDER FOR AUTO DOOR (1M)</td>
                                                                <td>LUFTZYLINDER FÜR AUTOMATIKTÜR (1M)</td>
                                                                <td>#NAME?</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                                                    <button onclick="EditID(&quot;8BC84066-75B9-5DF8-68A7-AB02ADEABD09&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                        <img src="bilder/edit.png">
                                                                        </button>
                                                                        <br>
                                                                            <button style="color:red" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;8BC84066-75B9-5DF8-68A7-AB02ADEABD09&quot;)" class="toolBtn">-</button>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="ext-align: center">
                                                                            <button onclick="copyID(&quot;8BC84066-75B9-5DF8-68A7-AB02ADEABD09&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                                <img src="bilder/copy.png">
                                                                                </button>
                                                                            </td>
                                                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center">
                                                                                <button onclick="setChecked(&quot;8BC84066-75B9-5DF8-68A7-AB02ADEABD09&quot;,)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                                    <img src="bilder/check.png">
                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                                <td style="background-color:rgb(0,255,0,0.2)">2019-02-20</td>
                                                                                <td>エアシリンダ</td>
                                                                                <td>AIR CYLINDER</td>
                                                                                <td>LUFTZYLINDER</td>
                                                                                <td>VERIN PNEUMATIQUE</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td style="text-align: center">
                                                                                    <button onclick="EditID(&quot;2C08FF64-5A97-564B-55C3-A54F03C93809&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                                        <img src="bilder/edit.png">
                                                                                        </button>
                                                                                        <br>
                                                                                            <button style="color:red" onclick="deleteRow(&quot;2C08FF64-5A97-564B-55C3-A54F03C93809&quot;)" class="toolBtn">-</button>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        <td style="ext-align: center">
                                                                                            <button onclick="copyID(&quot;2C08FF64-5A97-564B-55C3-A54F03C93809&quot;)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                                                <img src="bilder/copy.png">
                                                                                                </button>
                                                                                            </td>
                                                                                            <td style="border-right: 1px solid #cdd0d4;text-align: center">
                                                                                                <button onclick="setChecked(&quot;2C08FF64-5A97-564B-55C3-A54F03C93809&quot;,)" class="toolBtn">
                                                                                                    <img src="bilder/check.png">
                                                                                                    </button>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td style="background-color:rgb(255,255,0,0.2)">unchecked</td>
                                                                                                <td>振動シリンダ</td>
                                                                                                <td>OSCILLATING CYLINDER</td>
                                                                                                <td>SCHWENKZYLINDER</td>
                                                                                                <td>VERIN OSCILLANT</td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
```

Idk why it is formatted wrong but u can open it with ure browser to get a better overview!

Hope u can help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead

Comment: Oh yes i forgot to write a possible solution like a vertically fixed header. But it should scroll horizontally.

Comment: you can try this 
https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Comment: Won't the x-scrollable-only wrapper element take care of the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @Guru1988 i saw this solution earlyer but it wont siut with a horizontally scrollable table. Ty for ure fast answer!

Comment: @teemu Im able to scroll in both directions with the whole table. Just the header should stay fixed if i scroll down.