# Sticky multiple table header (thead) rows using only css/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have multiple rows under the `<thead>` tag be stickied while the rest of the table is scrollable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead/59690013#59690013) answer on SO shows how to sticky the header to the top using `position: sticky` tag but doesn't show how to sticky multiple rows within `<thead>`.

Using the CSS code mentioned in the link `thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }` will only sticky the first row within `<thead>`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If both the top values are same then, it is going to overlap one on each other, change the second header's `top` value with first header's `height`. Shown below

```
thead tr:nth-child(1) th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
thead tr:nth-child(2) th { position: sticky; top: 43px; }
```

Here `top: 43px` is a height of first header's

**Full Example**
//HTML

```
<table id="customers">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Company 2</th>
    <th>Contact 2</th>
    <th>Country 2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
    <td>Some repeated content</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

//CSS

```
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
thead tr:nth-child(1) th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
thead tr:nth-child(2) th { position: sticky; top: 43px; }
```

Example link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/L4yd2brm/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works for most pages but the website is no longer responsive so if I resize the window because I am using px values for the second thead row, it messes up the design. Would you happen to have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Agreed, what if the high is dynamic (unknown) or changes?  There should be a way to group the rows and apply sticky to the group instead of each row.