# Sticky multiple row header and multiple columns using vanilla JavaScript in a container I can't control

Tags: html, css, html-table

My code will return the HTML for a table that will be put inside of a container (such as a `div`). I have no control of this root container/`div` but my code can put anything inside, like nesting a `div` if necessary.

The table will have rows and columns that may extend beyond the viewport of the parent container.

- The table will have 2-3 rows in a `thead` that need to be stuck/frozen on vertical scroll.
- The table will have X # of columns that need to be stuck/frozen on horizontal scroll.

I am trying to use `position: sticky` but not having luck.

I saw [Sticky multiple table header (thead) rows using only css/bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690342/sticky-multiple-table-header-thead-rows-using-only-css-bootstrap) but that doesn't work cause it requires setting an explicit height for each of the rows in he `thead` and I can't do that since the content in the `thead` rows may be of variable height.

In the example below, I included the root/parent container `div` but that is for example. I can't change it's properties. I can add more `div`s inside if needed.

```css
table, th, td
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead
{
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

tbody td.stuck
{
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1
}



/* I have no control of this DIV */
/* I am just putting it here for an example */
div
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="20">one</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solutions just using `top` and `left` of those sticky elements.
If the `td.stuck` cannot be a fixed width, you could throw a javascript to calculate the width.

```css
table, th, td
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

thead
{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

tbody td.stuck
{
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

tbody td.stuck:nth-child(2) {
  left: 51px;
}



/* I have no control of this DIV */
/* I am just putting it here for an example */
div
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="20">one</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td class="stuck">cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But the borders go all funky and you can see behind them...

Comment: Hey, that border thing seems like a bug. I added this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412922/9853981