# Sticky HTML table header works, but header outline disappears when scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using a React table library called react-bootstrap-table2, and added the following CSS to make the top row sticky:

```
.table-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.react-bootstrap-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The sticky header is working, but when I start scrolling, the header outline goes away. Any way to prevent this?

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-2-7ttsi)

**Before Scrolling:**
[image: Before]

**After Scrolling:**
[image: After]

Comment: so you want to keep the bottom border visible?

Comment: Both top and borders would be visible ideally.

Comment: ok i see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266262/position-sticky-on-thead that is not possible to make sticky the thead tag, do you really need the thead on top? adding the border to th is not enough?

Comment: Yes thead needs to be on top, that's generated by the table component I'm using. I haven't tried adding a border to th. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your has the table has

```
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Which means that the borders are collapsed. I do not know the exact reason, why it is initially visible but disappears on the scroll.

If you want to retain your border on a scroll, try doing this

```
table {
 border-collapse: separate;
}
```

but this breaks the UI of the table, as it adds gaps between cells

My solution is to add a border using  multiple box shadows

```
.table th {
    box-shadow: 0 1px #dee2e6, 0 -1px #dee2e6;/*1st for bottom, 2nd for top*/
}
```

Here is [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-2-5zmbk)

Also change value of `top` to `1px`

```
.react-bootstrap-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pseudo element to create the border, so it stays with the `th`:

```
.react-bootstrap-table .table-bordered {
  border-top: none;
}

.react-bootstrap-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: none;
}

.react-bootstrap-table th::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: -2px;
  width: calc( 100% + 2px);
  height: 1px;;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
}

.react-bootstrap-table th::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  width: calc( 100% + 2px);
  height: 1px;;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
}
```

I changed the `top` to 0 on the th as well.

Edit to keep bottom border.

Comment: This preserved the top border but not bottom.

Comment: @Ravi then use another pseudo element `::after`. Answer updated.